# Is it possible to block the Wifi access for an individual application(Mac OS X 10.7)

Tags: macos, applications, network, wifi

I would like to disable the network connection for an individual applications in Mac OS X 10.7

Lets say an example, I don't want to provide the network access for photoshop application.

Is it possible ?

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install and use [LittleSnitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) to easily block outgoing network connections on a per-application basis. (Can also configure incoming blocks as well, if you wish.)

If you're trying to defeat network copy protection in Adobe Photoshop and certain other apps -- you can prevent Photoshop from "phoning home" across the internet, but you can't prevent it from detecting multiple serial numbers on the LAN. At the LAN level it uses protocols other than TCP/IP to see if other same-serial-number copies of the program are running. LittleSnitch can't recognize or filter these non-TCP/IP communications.

Comment: LittleSnitch is good

Comment: By curiosity, which other protocols would Photoshop use ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the in built sandbox-exec application for somethings related to this, you need to create a special no-network profile and need to launch the target application using sandbox-exec. You can refer to the article [here](http://abhisanoujam.blogspot.com/2009/06/meet-macs-sandbox-exec.html) for more detailed explanation on this.

Another application which i havent used but is supposed to do the same is [TCPBlock](http://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/prevent-mac-apps-from-using-internet-connection-with-tcpblock/)

Both are free unlike LittleSnitch